# How to show an error when the database connection failed?

Tags: php, database-connection, database-migration, yii2-basic-app

I have an application using Yii2 Basic and use User Dektrium. The application doesn't give an error message if there an error in database configuration. 
for example, in db.php, I've set the wrong database password so the application won't process the login action, but it also doesn't show an error message.

**How can I set an error message to be shown when there an error in database configuration?**

Comment: Without seeing any code, this will be very difficult to answer.

Comment: May I know which code part that I need to show in here? Thanks

Comment: For MySQL, it's like `mysql_connect(....) or die("DB connection failed");`

Answer (score 0):

You could check Whether the DB connection is established before you proceed with the login action 
[http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#getIsActive()-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#getIsActive()-detail/%20'Get%20Is%20Active')